# Delete rows in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have the following code, but I can't seem to manipulate it to work the way I want. I would like to have the command search the data base for the first entry in the database that matches `textbox2.text` and delete the row.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DillPickle\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From ACCNT where ACCNTNUM=" + textBox2.Text , con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        ACCNT."txtbox2.text".Rows[0].Delete();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The account does not exist in the record!");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Your code is vulnerable to Sql injection and 2) you're not deleting the first entry, you're only deleting it if there is only one match. Oh, and 3) What is `ACCNT."txtbox2.text"`??

Comment: You're deleting from your datatable, not the database itself. Also, your logic will always return zero or one result. That result isn't the row related to your account number, it's just a count of how many rows contain that account number.

Comment: Personally I would do this with a single query. Just delete the row and then check how many rows were affected to determine if it existed or not.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do; here's one way:

```
private readonly string SqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DillPickle\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
private readonly string SqlDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM ACCNT WHERE ACCNTNUM=@accountNumber";

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
        using (var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            sqlCommand.CommandText = SqlDeleteQuery;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountNumber", textBox2.Text);

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do something with the exception, like log it...
    }
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks so much for the assistance. I feel like i understand the function more now that I know what it looks like.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer and upvote if it helped you. :)